# Is there a way to bring remote branches to local using pull?

Tags: git, github

Just want to double check a few things here:

1) So git pull --rebase will pull changes from the remote master but it will not pull any remote branches, right? I tried to do this and the remote branch didn't appear in my local list of branches as I thought it will bring everything from the remote site.

2) To pull remote branches to work on them locally I should use fetch followed by checkout, right?

3) Is there a way to pull remote branches locally using pull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) ... it will not pull any remote branches, right?

Aside from the one checked out, correct, but it will `fetch` all the remote's branches as tracking branches `<remote>/<branch>` e.g. `origin/master` and then `merge` the local branch you currently have checked out with the remote branch you have setup to track, either explicitly or by default.

You can see a full list of local and tracking branches with:

```
git branch -avv
```

> 2) To pull remote branches to work on them locally I should use fetch followed by checkout, right?

Yes if you do not have a local branch yet, then `checkout` will create it. However, if you do have one, then you'll need to `merge` (or `pull`) after `checkout`

> 3) Is there a way to pull remote branches locally using pull?

Yes, the easiest way I can think of is to create an alias that will `checkout` all the branches, but you really don't want to do this in my opinion. There's no real advantage to eager loading all the local branches, so just check them out when you're actually ready to work on them.

Answer (score 3):

`git pull` pulls branches from the remote.

`git pull` is essentially `git fetch && git merge` by default.

`git pull --rebase` just rebases your code before merging the changes from the upstream branch into the current branch you are on. Git will execute this rebase instead of doing a merge. Be careful with this because you can really screw things up if you aren't careful.

To work on remote branches you can `git fetch && git checkout` to checkout a local version of the remote branch. As `git pull` is just `git fetch && git merge`, `git pull` also works in the place of `git fetch`, but you may end up with weird changes to your repo if the tip of the upstream branch is both ahead of the tip of your working branch.

Crucially, `git fetch` will fetch **all** branches from the remote unless you specify one, and by extension `git pull` will too.

Comment: As an addendum. Any freshly pulled remote branches will not show on `git branch --list` output until they are checked out for the first time. To display a list of all branches, local and remote, use `git branch --list -r`

Comment: or `git branch -rvv`